# What are the default values for maven requireJavaVersion enforce rule

Tags: java, maven, maven-enforcer-plugin

I have a maven project where I do not specify anything about what java version that needs to be enforced, however it seems that [1.8.0-31,1.9) is picked up and fails my project as I'm using 1.7.0-72.

Is this controlled by what version of maven-enforcer-plugin is used ? This would be maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce in my case. I also have no references to this in settings.xml.

I'm running on OSX where I do in fact have 1.8.0-31 installed, but not currently set as active.

Any ideas/pointers where/what I should look at to find out why [1.8.0-31,1.9) is enforced ?

Cheers,
Niklas

Comment: have you looked at https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireJavaVersion.html

Comment: I assume you have a parent which likely defines the maven-enforcer-plugin with the versions....

Comment: Yep we did have an uber-super pom that had a requireVersion.